# React Native AlertIOS.prompt(args) is called constantly even though it is onPress

Tags: react-native

I added to code text component like this:

```
      <Text 
        style={styles.text}
        onPress={
          AlertIOS.prompt(
            'title', 'defaultValue',  
            [{text: 'Cancel', onPress: this.onCancel.bind(this)}, 
            {text: 'OK', onPress: this.onOk.bind(this)}])}
        >
          press me!
      </Text>
```

but as I ran simulator, the prompt was called immediately after mounting the screen and was continually displayed over and over, whether I clicked a OK/cancel button on it or not.

I have no other AlertIOS.prompt() calls anywhere in my code.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in React-native?

Comment: why not just use AlertIOS.alert ?

Comment: Try this:  onPress: () => this.onOk

Comment: adding () => this.onOk works, thank you very much!

Comment: Could you please put a full working example and mark it as an answer?